# Eliminating nested each

Tags: ruby, iteration

I have an unusual data structure that I need to search - the structure is the result of parsing a JSON file returned from an HTTP request.

The top-level object is an Array, but from top to bottom I have `Array->Hash->Array->Hash`.

I'm writing code to check the value of a given key in the innermost hash, across the entire data structure.

As it stands, my code is like this:

```
json = JSON.parse(File.read(file))
json.each do |hash1|
  hash1.keys.each do |key|
    hash1[key].each do |inner_hash|
      # search in the inner hash
    end
  end
end
```

I know this is ugly. I know there are better ways to iterate over collections and to combine selections together. I'm just not sure what I should do in this instance given the repeated sliding from array to hash.

**What I'm Searching**

In the above code, I have the search snipped out. My goal with this iteration structure is to skim through entries (the hashes at the `entry_id` level) for various conditions and either immediately act on or return the Hash object when the conditions are met. For example, if the condition is that `field1` contains `something`, I might want to return

```
[
  {
    "entry_id": 544,
    "field1": "something",
    "field2": "something else",
    "field3": 456
  },
  {
    "entry_id": 546,
    "field1": "something!",
    "field2": "something else!",
    "field3": 012
  }
]
```

**Example of Data Structure**

```
[
{
  "12345": [
    {
      "entry_id": 543,
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "other value",
      "field3": 123
    },
    {
      "entry_id": 544,
      "field1": "something",
      "field2": "something else",
      "field3": 456
    }
  ],
  "23456": [
    {
      "entry_id": 545,
      "field1": "new value",
      "field2": "other new value",
      "field3": 789
    },
    {
      "entry_id": 546,
      "field1": "something!",
      "field2": "something else!",
      "field3": 012
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: Please paste a short (but complete) example of that data-structure, otherwise you are forcing everyone to prepare one for testing purposes.

Comment: D'oh, I should have done that! Thanks, example added.

Comment: thanks. More questions: what's in the search? what value must be returned?

Comment: Edited question to address your question. This is an example - there is more than one potential use and more than one potential return result. At times I may want to collect an array of objects, at times I may want to handle matching objects inline.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the hashes/arrays using a custom enumerator (modified from a StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748761/1614607)):

```
def dfs(obj, &blk)
  return enum_for(:dfs, obj) unless blk      
  yield obj if obj.is_a? Hash
  if obj.is_a?(Hash) || obj.is_a?(Array)
    obj.each do |*a|
      dfs(a.last, &blk)
    end
  end
end
```

You can then use this enumerator builder method in any number of other helper methods for whatever you need. For example, to perform your example search, you could define:

```
def find_node_with_value(obj, key, value)
  dfs(obj).select do |node|
    node[key].respond_to?(:include?) && node[key].include?(value)
  end
end
```

And then use it like:

```
find_node_with_value(json_data, "field1", "something")
# [{"entry_id"=>544, "field1"=>"something" ...}, {"entry_id"=>546, "field1"=>"something!" ...}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [JSONPath](https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath), which gives you XPath-like querying of JSON objects.

Note that the leading zero in your sample JSON makes it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
json = JSON.parse(File.read(file))
inner_hashes = json.lazy.map{|hash| hash.values }.flatten
results = inner_hashes.select{|x| ... }
```

`lazy` is from ruby 2.0. It's just there to let you deal with the items one at a time as they are found.

This solution assumes you don't care about the keys of the first level of hashes.